# Apache POI - XSLFConnectorShape

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am starting a new project which I need to export our diagrams to PPTX (PowerPoint). I already have the JSON files that we used to draw it on a browser but now I will take it and convert to Power Point file which I must have to draw every shape and line in order to provide the drag 'n drop feature to the final user (I could take one image and put into a slide, but no, has to be power point, only!, no svg, no visio)

I am still evaluating the available options like Apache POI (HSLF/XSFL) and Aspose.Slides for Java (paid).

There is one feature that I missing most in the ApachePOI which the XSLFConnectorShape (I want it in the final diagram then the user can drag a particular shape and the line follows it). Checking all the possibilities on Google, Apache POI docs are really poor related to PowerPoint and in one of their mailing list from 2012 http://markmail.org/thread/sy7s463cudtlc7i5 looks like no one implemented this yet. I found one very very complicated example (which is not working) that creates a CTConnector from another openxmlformat library and so on.

I wonder if someone already did this and can share an example using ApachePOI, again the documentation is poor which has nothing pointing this and the examples don't help much.

Question 2: For drawing PPT from scratch would guys recommend any other library rather than POI or paid Aspose.Slides ?

Thanks in advance.

This is what I've found in some apache-poi git repos

```
public static void connect(XSLFSlide slide, XSLFAutoShape start, XSLFAutoShape end){
    XSLFConnectorShape connector = slide.createConnector();
    connector.setAnchor(new Rectangle2D.Double(start.getAnchor().getX() + 100, start.getAnchor().getCenterY(), 100, 1));

    CTConnector ctConnector = (CTConnector)connector.getXmlObject();
    ctConnector.getSpPr().getPrstGeom().setPrst(STShapeType.STRAIGHT_CONNECTOR_1);

    CTNonVisualConnectorProperties cx = ctConnector.getNvCxnSpPr().getCNvCxnSpPr();

    // connection start
    CTConnection stCxn = cx.addNewStCxn();
    stCxn.setId(start.getShapeId());
    // side of the rectangle to attach the connector: left=1, bottom=2,right=3, top=4
    stCxn.setIdx(3);

    CTConnection endCxn = cx.addNewEndCxn();
    endCxn.setId(end.getShapeId());
    // side of the rectangle to attach the connector: left=1, bottom=2,right=3, top=4
    endCxn.setIdx(3);
}
```

Aparently it works, but.... really poor in terms of customizing it and also deal with low-level xml isnt the best approach.

Comment: When it's not implemented, using the low-level xmlbeans is your best bet. So when I'd implement it, I'd do as Yeagor (in your linked thread) recommends: saving the pptx and see what's in the slide#.xml (in the zip-file). I think we only have 1 open ticket about connectors and it's a really seldom asked feature. If you think the documentation is poor, please provide examples or changes to the webpage (via a bugzilla entry), which make it better ... we are happy to commit user input ...

Comment: @kiwiwings thanks for your input. Well, without knowing the format is really tricky to do the reverse engineering. You know, the format is created by Microsoft, hehe this says everything. I am kidding. So, sorry, I didn't want to sound rude when I mentioned poor documentation, I meant, by the ASF standards, this project has very few documentation and example regarding ppt, I say this because I'm dev that uses most of the ASF project maven (ant), tomcat, io, utils, lang3, so on. Once I get I a better shape with my project I will provide more examples. Thanks.

Comment: A small correction: The Idx values are not as you mentioned in your code comment. In reality it is:  top=0, left=1, bottom=2, right=3